# Count rows having status "closed" and status "unclosed" for every month in a year

Tags: mysql

This is the table, I need to get count of rows for status cloesd and status unclosed for every month in a year. Thanks in advance.

The table image

[image]

Comment: the table is given on clicking the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT MONTH(mt1.calltime) AS MONTH, YEAR(mt1.`calltime`) AS YEAR, COUNT(mt1.`status`) AS closed, 0 AS unclosed
        FROM myTable mt1
        WHERE mt1.`status`='closed'
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT MONTH(mt2.calltime) AS MONTH, YEAR(mt2.`calltime`) AS YEAR, 0 AS closed, COUNT(mt2.`status`) AS unclosed
        FROM myTable mt2
        WHERE mt2.`status`='unclosed'
    )
) AS tablea
GROUP BY tablea.month
```

Replace `myTable` with your tablename.

`MONTH` will extract month of the year from the given date, and `YEAR` will give year.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89ead2/1)**

Comment: THanks bro. Made my query

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from table1
where status in ('closed,unclosed')
group by status,month(call_time)
```

Comment: actually, i need the result for both if status is closed and unclosed like for date, result be like: http://imgur.com/a/P041d

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table name> WHERE status="closed"; 


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table name> WHERE status="unclosed";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get year part from the date using [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and month part using [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions and `status` column from the table and use this as a subset and then use `CASE` expression to count the `Closed` and `Unclosed` status group by the year and month.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.`YEAR`, t.`MONTH`,
SUM(CASE t.`status` WHEN 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Closed`,
SUM(CASE t.`status` WHEN 'Unclosed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `UnClosed`
FROM(
    SELECT YEAR(`call_time`) AS `YEAR`,
    MONTH(`call_time`) AS `MONTH`,
    `status`
    FROM `your_table_name`
)t
GROUP BY t.`YEAR`, t.`MONTH`;
```

***[`SQL Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddf42/1)***